# Run python script from Docker

Tags: python, bash, docker

Trying to run test Python script from Docker using Bash. Win10 OS.
I have a file `print.py` in the directory `C:/Py/test`

1. run this `$ cd C:/Py/test`
2. run this `$ docker run --volume $(pwd):/home/${USER} python:3.7 python /home/${USER}/print.py`

Got this error:  `python: can't open file 'C:/Program Files/Git/home/print.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Why is this file trying to be found in the `C:/Program Files/Git/home/` directory instead of `C:\Py\test`?

`$ python 'print.py'` is working

[image]

Comment: Why not just run `docker run python:3.7 print.py` ?

Comment: If you have a working host Python installation, why introduce Docker into it?  Can you build a self-contained image with your application code built in, instead of using a bind mount?  (This initially sounds like a Windows shell problem to me.)

Comment: @MarkSetchell got this: `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "print.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.`

Comment: @DavidMaze Just for training purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git bash prepended its installation path, try these two methods :

1. Use:   //home/${USER}/print.py
2. Run with: MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 docker run ...

Comment: It works: `$ MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 docker run --volume $(pwd):/home/${USER} python:3.7 python /home/${USER}/print.py`
Thanks!